# How far is too far with fluent C#?

Tags: c#, coding-style, fluent-interface

```
public static class Th
{
    public static T e<T>(T theObject) where T : class
    {
        return theObject;
    }        
}

public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static bool Is<T>(this T o, Func<T, bool> a) where T : class
    {
        return a(o);
    }
}

//...

//logic in a method somewhere
Func<string, bool> valid = property => _myService.SomeValidationMethod(property);

if (Th.e(_request.Property).Is(valid))
{
   //do something
}
```

Is this code suitable for production and why?

**Edit:** Thank you for all your comments. I hope you had as much fun reading my stretching of the C# syntax to breaking point as I did reading your responses.

Comment: It's unreadable... A bunch of comments needed to understand... It hurts my eyes and mind. :)

Comment: Well isn't that fun and a bit pointless.

Comment: You create a hypothesis and then ask us to prove it?  Why don't you say why it is suitable for production?

Comment: It's quite suitable for thedailywtf.com

Comment: You sacrificed readability in most of your code in order to get a semi-fluent one-liner. Unmaintainable, and not worth the trouble IMHO.

Comment: For me - this surely triggers `WTF?!!`

Comment: @gmagana To be clear, I am not making any hypothesis. I am merely looking for a consensus on the validity of the code. Which I duly received!

Comment: @Ben Aston I believe that there is a reason some of the more "English" languages have disappeared into obscurity ;-) I don't think "fluent" and "English" should be confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no problem with fluent APIs, but this seems to violate the principle of least surprise.  I would not understand the purpose of a class named `Th` nor of a method named `e`.

Comment: ... that only returns its argument.

Comment: I was wondering what purpose that served.

Comment: @Marlon to make it more "fluent" of course. dooh!

Answer (score 2):

What makes you think that this code is 'fluent' ?

this is absolutely not fluent, nor self documenting.

Comment: Likely because one can read `if (Th.e(_request.Property).Is(valid))` as a sentence if he manages to stay alive while ignoring all braces, underscores and dots.

Comment: @Amis, nice, I stopped reading the first time long before that line.

Answer (score 2):

That is too far. No, the code is not suitable for production. `Th.e` is neither correctly phrased prose nor appropriately-named code - it's meaningless in both contexts.

Answer (score 1):

While what you call "fluency" is extremely important, and most developers are missing that (even who should really care about this, like CS algorithm writers), the code style you showed us is abusing expressibility of the language and not very useful, IMO, for 2 reasons:

- `if (_request.Property.Is(valid))` would be "fluent" enough even without those `Th` class and `Th.e` method;
- Because of this "fluency" your are loosing precious identifiers. What if you need to verify another object? You do `if (Th.e(_request.Property2).Is(valid))` or `if (Th.e(_request2.Property).Is(valid))`? What if you need to perform another test? You do `if (Th.e(_request.Property).Is(valid2))`?